# Real time web page

Tags: real-time

I want to build simple web based app, where users, for example, could push the spacebar button, and then do something further, like answer a question, and while other users at the same time only sees that this question is not available any more for answer. When user submits answer, everyone see it.

All right, here is an example. I have seen TV shows, where four players have one button, if one or two of them know answer, they hit a button, and one lamp turns on and the first is allowed to answer, while other keeps their mouths shut. I want to build the same idea, but in the web.

But problem is that, I don't know where to start, what keywords I should search for help on google and so on. I see, that it might work on HTML5, maybe JavaScript and so on.

I have idea using Ajax, but request it every second to get latest actions made seems rubbish. Also I found one service called Pusher, but it  has limited users in one time, which doesn't fit my needs.

I need just ideas. Thanks.

Comment: You might want to try a ready-made solution for making any web page real-time and interactive. Check out Lightstreamer: http://www.lightstreamer.com (disclaimer: I am the CTO).

Answer (score 1):

Before you read the rest, a disclaimer: I work for Realtime.co but I do believe I can help here so I'm not trying to "pitch a sale".

You can check out Realtime ([www.realtime.co](http://www.realtime.co)). It's basically a set of tools for developers to use real time technologies on their projects. It uses websockets but does fallback to whatever the user's browser supports (such as long polling, for example).

Behind Realtime you have a one-to-one/one-to-many/many-to-many messaging system that will transport your messages to and from your users.

There's also a plus which is the fact that the Realtime framework is actually cross-platform. This means that you can even have your web users communicate with iPhone users, Android, users, Windows Phone, desktop applications, server applications, etc..

You can learn about the JavaScript API here: http://docs.xrtml.org/getting_started/hello_message.html#javascript.

You only need to register at [Realtime.co](http://www.realtime.co) as a developer and start using the free license.

I really hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Okey, I think I will go with node.js.

Writing all this previous post, made me think in right way :)

Comment: That will work but you'll spend quite some time just to get it functioning. If you go with a ready-to-use solution, you'll spend way less time fiddling with communication and more time developing your application's logic. Give a framework such as Realtime.co's a chance and you'll get started in minutes (really).

Comment: Thanks Spac3Rat, but I already learnt Node.js in pretty good level :) Out there on Internet are some very good examples and tutorials.